# Default inheritance type in C#

Tags: c#

I want to know which is the default inheritance type in C#. for example, the default inheritance type in c++ is private by default as follows.

```
class A{}
class B:A
```

Here we inherit all the members of class A as a private member. In such way what is default inheritance type in c# & the default class type in C#. How we come to know that whether a particular member in base class is acessible in derived class or not?
Please explain with example.

Comment: @mxmissile: Please go easy on new members.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only inheritance type in C# is `public`.

Comment: Maybe a bit of explanation could be given ?